# Equals method used in Map key comaprison

Tags: java, dictionary, equals

I know that it is not possible to extend a class which overrides the method `equals()` and to keep it "preserved" when someone adds a new aspect in a subclass. The common example with class `Point` and a subclass of it demonstates it:

```
public class Point {

    Double d1;
    Double d2;

    public Point(double d1, double d2){
        this.d1 = d1;
        this.d2 = d2;
    }
}

public class ColorPoint extends Point {

    String color;

    public ColorPoint(double d1, double d2, String s) {
        super(d1, d2);
        color = s;
    }
}
```

If we have Eclipse to create the method `equals()` and `hashCode()`, it takes into consideration also the color attribute in the case of `ColorPoint`. Therefore the `equals()` method is proved to be not symmetric. The code:

```
Point p1 = new Point(2,2);
ColorPoint cp1 = new ColorPoint(2, 2, "blue");

System.out.println(p1.equals(cp1));
System.out.println(cp1.equals(p1));
```

prints:

true
false

In the same way it can be proved that the method is not transisive. However when I pass the Objects as keys in a `HasMap`, it recognizes them as different, irespective of the order I pass them. The code:

```
Point p1 = new Point(2,2);
Point p2 = new Point(3.1,3.1);
ColorPoint cp1 = new ColorPoint(2, 2, "blue");
ColorPoint cp2 = new ColorPoint(3.1,3.1, "red");


Map<Point, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(cp2, 4); map.put(cp1, 3);
map.put(p1, 1); map.put(p2, 2); 

System.out.println(map.size());
```

prints always 4, even if I pass the Objects in another order. Is that expected? So, which method is used by the `Map` in order to compare the keys?

Comment: What do the `equals()` methods look like?

Comment: There is only one `equals` for each object and that's the one the `Map` uses. And you are right, you can't have a subclass `equals` a superclass and keep symmetry.

Comment: As said by the name, the `HashMap` uses the hash code of your objects, which will likely be different for all your objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably because the hashcode() generated by eclipse takes into account the color field of the ColourPoint, so the points and colorpoints hash to different buckets and are never compared with equals().

Note that this implies that the contract for hashcode() is broken - two objects for which a.equals(b) == true are producing different hashcodes. Basically, don't do this!

The Scala language has an interesting take on this, using a canEqual method to determine whether two objects can ever be equal. Check it out [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MFjNhTjeQKkC&pg=PA555&lpg=PA555&dq=scala%20canequal&source=bl&ots=FLrnSJMOvv&sig=17OUpdKN3CN9zn6Xxngl6pahxWc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DjGaUY3ZD4vP0AWjpoDQCg&ved=0CEsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=scala%20canequal&f=false).

Comment: Should we refrain from passing Objects from sublasses of the class defined as key in a Map? Is there any way to get over this? (To apply this without negative implications)

Comment: Absolutely not - the key is to write your equals() and hashcodes() property. In Java the simplest way is to mandate that a Point can never equal a ColouredPoint, so in the equals method of Point have something like if (other.getClass() != Point.class) etc. This exact point is made in Effective Java by Josh Bloch.

Comment: Josh Bloch: "There is no way to extend an instantiable class and add a value component while preserving the equals contract". The Scala link I provided above disagrees with that point... but that's in Scala, not Java!